# VHDL code does not synthesize

Tags: vhdl

I have written 2 state machines in my VHDL code. The simulation works fine, but the code does not synthesize. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_arith.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity pulse_width is
Port (  clk : in STD_LOGIC;
            timer2:in std_logic;
            input: in STD_LOGIC;
            result: inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
            SEL_LINE: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 DOWNTO 0);
            data_out: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (23 downto 0):=x"000000");
end pulse_width;

architecture Behavioral of pulse_width is
    TYPE count_states is (s0,s0_dash,s1,s2,s3,s1_dash);
    SIGNAL current_state, next_state : count_states := s0 ;
    TYPE write_states is (ws0,ws0_dash,ws1,ws2,ws3,ws4);
    SIGNAL current_state1, next_state1 : write_states := ws0 ;
    TYPE index_array is ARRAY(integer range 0 to 65535) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    SIGNAL mem: index_array;
    SIGNAL count: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):=x"0000";
    SHARED VARIABLE j: integer:=0;
    SHARED VARIABLE a,i: integer:=1;
    SIGNAL flag,push_data,push_first,push_final,push_pulses,rw_first,rw_end: std_logic:='0';
    SIGNAL y_clk_input ,y_clk_timer2, enable_count: std_logic:='0';
    SIGNAL first,final: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):= x"0001";

begin
-- Pulse width count

process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        current_state<=next_state;
        current_state1<=next_state1;
    end if;
end process;


process(input,SEL_LINE,current_state)
begin

------------------------------------------------------------------------
    case current_state is
    when s0 => 
        if(input='1') then
            next_state<=s1;
        else
            next_state<=s0;
        end if;
    when s1 =>
        flag<='0';
        if input='1' then
            count <= count+ x"0001";
            next_state<=s1_dash;
        else
            next_state<=s2;
        end if;         
    when s1_dash =>
        if input='1' then
            count <= count+ x"0001";
            next_state<=s1;
        else
            next_state<=s2;
        end if;         
    when s2 =>
            result <= count;
            next_state<=s3;
    when s3=>
            count <= x"0000";
            next_state<=s0;
            enable_count<='0';
    when others =>
        next_state<=s0;
    end case;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    case current_state1 is
    when ws0 =>
        if  (result>x"0000") then
        next_state1<=ws1;
        else
        next_state1<=ws0_dash;
        end if;
    when ws0_dash =>
        if  (result>x"0000") then
        next_state1<=ws1;
        else
        next_state1<=ws0;
        end if;
    when ws1=>
        if rw_first='1' and rw_end='1' then
        next_state1<=ws0;
        else
            mem(a) <= result;
            a:=a+1;
            final<=final+x"0001";
            next_state1<=ws2;
        end if;
    when ws2 =>
            next_state1<=ws0;
            result<=x"0000";
    when others  =>
        next_state1<=ws0;
    end case;
end process;
```

I eventually need to implement three state machines.

Comment: Can you post the error message of your synthesis tool? Also it is not a good idea to mix NUMERIC_STD with STD_LOGIC_ARITH and STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED. Instead you should use just NUMERIC_STD and its type conversion functions.

Answer (score 0):

The math you're trying to do in the asynchronous state logic is not registered and won't synthesize well.  You need to re-arrange your state logic so statements like:

```
count <= count+ x"0001";
...
final<=final+x"0001";
```

...are synchronous and not 'free running' in an asynchronous loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you read and write the same signals in one combinational process.

- Either put everything in one clocked (synchronous) process
- Or: use explicit registers: `count_next <= count + x"0001";`

Not related to your error, but still worth paying attention to:

You have a ton of unused signals and shared variables: 
push_data,push_first,push_final,push_pulses, y_clk_input ,y_clk_timer2, first, i,j
This is confusing for anybody trying to read your code. [1](http://www.sigasi.com/content/dead-code)

The packages STD_LOGIC_arith and STD_LOGIC_unsigned are [deprecated](http://www.sigasi.com/content/deprecated-ieee-libraries)